# Cannot restart mysql

Tags: mysql

I don't know why, all of a sudden I cannot open anymore MySQL. I get the following error:

> ```
> bomble@ChemAlive:~/ChemAliveCode/SABIC$ mysql -h localhost -u bomble
> ```
>
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I tried to restart MySQL doing:

```
bomble@ChemAlive:~/ChemAliveCode/SABIC$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
[sudo] password for bomble:
```

But it failed:

> * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld [ OK ]
>   * Starting MySQL database server mysqld [fail]

I had a look at my error.log file. Here's what it says:

> InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
>   InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
>   InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.

Don't know what that means?

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

If I restart using

```
service mysql restart
```

instead of

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

It restarts fine, and I can then login to MySQL.